# PHP imagepng() unable to generate images

Tags: php, apache

Here's my code:

```
    $img   = imagecreate(110, 20) or die("GD图像创建失败！");
    $bg    = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 55, 55, 55);
    imagestring($img, 5, 0, 3, "leo", $text_color);

    //header('content-type:image/png');
    imagepng($img,"/html/newfeicui/test/test.png");
    imagedestroy($img);
```

I post some of my phpinfo information:

[phpinfo information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7DBf.png)

[gd information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqT4q.png)

I can generate a picture by executing this PHP code under the shell but it's not okay to execute it through browser.

I found that it would have the following error by looking at Apache error log：

> [Wed Jan 03 09:57:59.102168 2018] [core:notice] [pid 800] AH00052:
>   child pid 2578 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

If I replace the `imagepng` with `imagejpeg` or `imagegif`, the browser will be successful, and only the `imagepng` will fail.

My running system is `centos7`

The Apache version is `2.4.6`

The PHP version is `5.6.31`

My English is not very good, I hope you can understand, thank you, this question has been bothering me for a week.

Comment: I am unable to replicate any error - it works fine (win7, apache 2.2,PHP5.3.2 ) Are you trying to output the image directly in the browser ( in a webpage for instance ) or just trying to save it?

Comment: hi @RamRaider ,I just want to save it, I'm in my test environment（win7,apache2.4.23,php5.6.25），It can also be run normally, and in a formal environment, I'm going to be wrong